# How to load local HTML file in UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am newbie to Objective-C.I want to know how to load the local html file(say index.html) into UIWebView,i can able to load the url like this,

```
  -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        NSLog(@"willAppear");

        UIWebView *myWebView=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 400, 400)];


        NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.google.co.in/"];

        [myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
        myWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
        [self.view addSubview:myWebView];
    }
```

I want to load the local html file instead of loading url.How do i do that?.

and also i want to call the delegate method

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
```

navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType,which is not being called.Any guidance is neatly appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all,please go through the apple document before searching in google.I suggest you to go through the basic objective c programming concept.

In reference to [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html),i would like to tell you how to load the local html.

```
UIWebView *myWebView=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 400, 400)];
NSString *indexPath = [NSBundle pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:nil];
[myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:indexPath]]];
[self.view addSubview:myWebView];
```

To call any delegate methods first implement the  UIWebViewDelegate protocol in your class..i.e. in your interface's declaration like below…

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>
```

Then set your webview delegate to your class..ie.,next after you initialize your web view.

```
myWebView.delegate = self;
```

Hope it works…Happy Coding :-)